# Sum a column at the bottom of it

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

In Google Sheets, how do I get - at the bottom-most cell of a column - the sum of each cell (except for row 1, the header) above in that column? Keep in mind, I may add rows in the future.

Comment: Thanks "user0". What would it be, for that same case, if I want to sum up the column ONLY if the sum is greater than zero? (I just don't want to see 0's when the column is blank. Also, I would like this to apply on all columns from C onwards, and I want to be able to add rows anywhere, (even before the last row - so, plain SUM function wouldn't fit for me.))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways how to solve this. The most simple would be to use dragging **`SUM`**:

[image: 0]

Then all you need to do is insert new rows inside of the **`SUM`** range so it would automatically expand as needed:

[image: 0]

As a next-level move, you can use **`ARRAYFORMULA`** with **`INDIRECT`** where you can use **`ROW()-1`** to always get the range from **A2** cell to the row where this formula resides minus 1 row:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(
 TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("A2:C"&ROW()-1)),
       ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW()-1))^0)))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

The formula provided is correct but does not take under consideration empty cells.

**To fix the empty cells issue** use the following corrected formula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(
 TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("A2:B"&ROW()-1))*1,
       ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW()-1))^0)))
```

[image]

*(notice the `*1`)*

Comment: Please check this answer which fixes the empty rows issue.